# Meteor React group collection

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have a Collection named `Items` with fields `name` and `category`.
In `/imports/api/Items.js` the *simpl-schema* is defined as:

```
const LibItems = new Mongo.Collection('libitems');
LibItems.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  category: String,
  text: String,
});
LibItems.attachSchema(LibItems.schema);
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('allLibItems', function () {
    return LibItems.find({}, );
  });
}
export default LibItems;
```

On the page, I want to group the items per unique category; and show only the Items of a selected category (by clicking on the category).
So on the bottom of the `imports/client/libview.js` the items are imported and unique categories are returned:

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('allLibItems');
  var libitems = LibItems.find({}, {sort: {category: 1}}).fetch();
  return {
    libitems: libitems,
    categories: _.uniq(
      libitems, false,
      function(libitems) {return libitems.category}
    ),
  }
}, LibView);
```

In the `render()` code, `renderCategory()` is called to list the categories:

```
renderCategories() {
  return this.props.categories.map((category) => {
    return (
      <li key={category._id} onClick={this.selectCategory.bind(null, category)}>{category.category}</li>
    );
  });
}
```

How to get the Items of a selected Category?
I'm relatively new to ReactJS and Meteor; and there might be a more elegant way of grouping items per unique categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `selectedCategory` variable is used to store the selected category, then you could it with `find` to get only items of the selected category.

```
export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('allLibItems');
  var libitems = LibItems.find({
    category: selectedCategory,
  }).fetch();

  return {
    libitems: libitems,
    categories: // ...,
  }
}, LibView);
```

**Update**

There are plenty of ways to store the selected category in `selectedCategory`, you just need to make sure that `selectedCategory` is reactive. Here I use [`ReactiveVar`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-var) to achieve that:

```
const selectedCategory = new ReactiveVar();

function setSelectedCategory(newVal) {
  selectedCategory.set(newVal);
}

export default createContainer(() => {
  Meteor.subscribe('allLibItems');
  const libitems = LibItems.find({
    category: selectedCategory.get(),
  }).fetch();

  return {
    // pass setSelectedCategory down to LibView
    setSelectedCategory: setSelectedCategory,
    libitems: libitems,
    categories: // ...,
  }
}, LibView);
```

Then inside `LibView` component:

```
selectCategory(category) {
  this.props.setSelectedCategory(category);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: How to pass on the `selectedCategory` state?

Comment: > Uncaught TypeError: this.setSelectedCategory is not a function at LibView.selectCategory

Comment: It is `this.props.setSelectedCategory` not `this.setSelectedCategory`